# Simple C# console app to take user input and calculate average for each user

Tags: c#, class, loops, object

I need to write a simple test console application in C# for school fundraising tracking. Here is what the expected output may look like. The user input prompts are to be placed inside of a loop so the program continues to ask for inputs until '999' is entered for the user's grade. If/when 999 value is entered, the program should calculate average value of the contributions and display the results with congratulation message to the largest collector.

//Create a class that will implement private variables that are needed. create class methods to accomplish the required functionality. In main method, instantiate one fundraiser object, and use that object to access the private variable. Does this problem even make sense? How do you carve out a class to accomplish all these tasks?

```
Sample output:
/*School Fund Raiser Tracker Application */

Please enter the grade of the contributor (6, 7 or 8)
(Enter 999  to exit):   6

Please enter the amount of the contribution: 100

Please enter the grade of the contributor (6, 7 or 8)
(Enter 999  to exit):  6

Please enter the amount of the contribution:  200

Please enter the grade of the contributor (6, 7 or 8)
(Enter 999  to exit): 7

Please enter the amount of the contribution:  500

Please enter the grade of the contributor (6, 7 or 8)
(Enter 999  to exit): 7

Please enter the amount of the contribution:  100

Please enter the grade of the contributor (6, 7 or 8)
(Enter 999  to exit):  999

Grade Level       # of Contrib   Total Amount      Average
6                    2                300             150
7                    2                600             300
```

My take at it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace FundRaiser
{
    public class SchoolFundRaiser
    {
        //public int grade { get; set; }
        //public double contribution { get; set; }
        public double average { get; set; }
        public int numOfContributions { get; set; }


        public void CalculateContribution()
        {
            int grade= 0; double contribution = 0.0;
            double total6 = 0.0, total7 = 0.0, total8 = 0.0, average6 = 0.0, average7 = 0.0, average8 = 0.0;
            int count6 = 0, count7 = 0, count8 = 0;
                while (grade != 999)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your grade(6, 7, 8). Enter 999 to quit.");
                    grade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (grade != 999)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Amount you want to contribute. ");
                        contribution = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
                    }

                    if (grade == 6)
                    {
                        total6 = total6 + contribution;
                        count6 = count6 +1;
                    }

                    if (grade == 7)
                    {
                        total7 = total7 + contribution;
                        count7 = count7 + 1;
                    }

                    else if (grade == 8)
                    {
                        total8 = total8 + contribution;
                        count8= count8 + 1;
                    }



                }

                average6 = total6 / count6;
                average7 = total7 / count7;
                average8 = total8 / count8;

                Console.WriteLine("Grade \t" + "Num of Contributions \t" + "Total Contribution \t" + "Average contribution");
                if (grade == 6)
                {
                    average = average6;
                    numOfContributions = count6;
                    Console.WriteLine(grade + "\t" + numOfContributions + "\t" + total6 + "\t" + average);
                }
                if (grade == 7)
                {
                    average = average7;
                    numOfContributions = count7;
                    Console.WriteLine(grade + "\t" + numOfContributions + "\t" + total7 + "\t" + average);
                }
                else
                {
                    average = average8;
                    numOfContributions = count8;
                    Console.WriteLine(grade + "\t" + numOfContributions + "\t" + total8 + "\t" + average);
                }

        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SchoolFundRaiser testSchoolFundRaiser = new SchoolFundRaiser();
            testSchoolFundRaiser.CalculateContribution();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you at least tried something? If so, please post it here.

Comment: @Szymon for some reason it chose to not show my code at first. Ctrl + K error?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Whats the question?

Comment: I hated the way i designed the class. I wanted to use arrays instead of all those variables.. How can I create arrays to keep track of user inputs for all the possible grades (6,7 or 8) as well as their respective contributions, so i can use them later to calculate average, total etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Dictionary` and Generic `List<>` if you want to make it more elegant. Below is the class that would accept the Grades and Contributions and then display the total number of contributions per grade and its average.

In the List there's Count property for getting the number of contributions per Grade, there is also `Sum()` method to get the total contributions per Grade and then finally there is `Average()` method to get the average contribution per Grade.

```
contri.Count, contri.Sum(), contri.Average()
```

One thing to note also in the key, value pair for the Dictionary I used
a `List<double>` for its value so that it could as many contributions per grade as the user wants, like:

```
private Dictionary<string, List<double>> entries = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
```

Here's the final code below:

```
class SchoolFundRaising
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<double>> entries = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
    public void displayContributionsSummary()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Grade \t Num of Contributions \t Total Contribution \t Average contribution");

        foreach (string key in entries.Keys)
        {
            List<double> contri = entries.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Key == key).Value;
            Console.WriteLine("Grade {0} \t {1}         \t      {2}              \t {3}", key, contri.Count, contri.Sum(), contri.Average());
        }
    }

    public void getContributionsGrades()
    {
        int grade = 0;
        double contribution;
        while (grade != 999)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your grade(6, 7, 8). Enter 999 to quit.");
            grade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (grade >= 6 && grade <= 8)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Amount you want to contribute. ");
                contribution = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                if (!entries.ContainsKey(grade.ToString()))
                {
                    List<double> dummyList = new List<double>();
                    dummyList.Add(contribution);
                    entries.Add(grade.ToString(), dummyList);
                }
                else
                {
                    entries.First(k => k.Key == grade.ToString()).Value.Add(contribution);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (grade == 999)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Done...");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Grade should either be 6,7 or 8");
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

You could then call in your main like this:

```
 SchoolFundRaising FR = new SchoolFundRaising();
 FR.getContributionsGrades();
 FR.displayContributionsSummary();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way by using contribution as object and dictionary to hold the contributions grade wise.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace FundRaiser
{
    class Program
    {
        public class GradeContribution
        {
            public GradeContribution()
            {
                this.Count = 0;
                this.Total = 0.0;
                this.Average = 0.0;
            }

            int grade;

            public int Grade
            {
                get { return grade; }
                set { grade = value; }
            }
            int count;

            public int Count
            {
                get { return count; }
                set { count = value; }
            }
            double total;

            public double Total
            {
                get { return total; }
                set { total = value; }
            }
            double average;

            public double Average
            {
                get { return average; }
                set { average = value; }
            }

        }

        public class SchoolFundRaiser
        {
            Dictionary<int, GradeContribution> contributionReciept;

            public SchoolFundRaiser()
            {
                contributionReciept = new Dictionary<int, GradeContribution>();
            }

            public void CalculateContribution()
            {
                int grade = 0;
                while (grade != 999)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter your grade(6, 7, 8).\n (Enter 999 to quit):");
                    grade = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (grade != 999)
                    {
                        GetContribution(grade);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Exiting...");
                        DisplayContribution();
                    }
                }
            }

            void GetContribution(int grade)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the Amount you want to contribute. ");
                double contribution = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                if (contributionReciept.ContainsKey(grade))
                {
                    GradeContribution contribute = contributionReciept[grade];
                    contribute.Count++;
                    contribute.Total += contribution;
                    contribute.Average = (contribute.Total / contribute.Count);
                }
                else
                {
                    GradeContribution contribute = new GradeContribution();
                    contribute.Grade = grade;
                    contribute.Count++;
                    contribute.Total += contribution;
                    contribute.Average = (contribute.Total / contribute.Count);
                    contributionReciept.Add(grade,contribute);
                }
            }

            void DisplayContribution()
            {
                var list = contributionReciept.Keys.ToList();
                list.Sort();

                Console.WriteLine("Grade \t" + "Num of Contributions \t" + "Total Contribution \t" + "Average contribution");

                foreach (var grade in list)
                {
                    GradeContribution gc = contributionReciept[grade];
                    Console.WriteLine(gc.Grade + "\t" + gc.Count + "\t" + gc.Total + "\t" + gc.Average);
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SchoolFundRaiser testSchoolFundRaiser = new SchoolFundRaiser();
            testSchoolFundRaiser.CalculateContribution();
        }
    }
}
```